# After opening project in Visual Studio, Blend stopped rendering the preview

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2010. When I open any projects created in Blend 4, and simply save it (no modification made), Blend stop rendering preview at the design time.

I am using Expression Blend 4.
Preview in Visual Studio 2010 is rendered.

So I think, there is some information in the project file, which is added by Visual Studio which prevents Blend from rendering controls. Any ideas of why is that happening?

Comment: You should have been around back in the days when we were using Blend 3 and VS2008... Seriously though, is your user control just not rendering or are you getting an error message in Blend? If you're getting an error message, what is it?

Comment: No error messages. Just empty control space instead of a UserControl/Custom control

Answer (score 0):

Installing Beta release of Service Pack for Visual Studio, seemed to fix the problem.